# Call a webservice that returns JSON from PostgreSQL

Tags: web-services, postgresql, psql

Is there a way for a function in PSQL to call a webservice that returns a JSON and use this JSON to perform something in the database within a trigger call ?

Comment: You can achieve something like that with the [`www_fdw`](https://github.com/cyga/www_fdw/wiki/Examples) [foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers). But I agree with [Craig's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34066732/1499698), you really shouldn't slow your regular DB operations with synchronous network requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`psql` is the command line client application. So no.

If you mean `pl/pgsql`, the server side function language, then ... still no. It, by design, cannot make network connections, access files, etc.

You could use PL/Python or PL/Perl to do this... but you shouldn't. If the web service is very slow, there are DNS problems, etc your whole database could slow to a nonfunctioning crawl.

Instead use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` with an external client to process a work queue and store the results in the database. With PostgreSQL 9.5's `SKIP LOCKED` this can be done concurrently very easily. With 9.4 and older it's easiest to do it serially, or using one worker managing multiple asynchronous requests.

This is much like the "how do I send email from a stored procedure" questions. You can use plperl or plpython, but you shouldn't.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the LISTEN and NOTIFY correctly the LISTEN will listen and notify to changes on a table from another database? is that correct ?

Comment: You have a client app written in perl/python/whatever that makes a normal database connection and `LISTEN`s for changes. You write triggers that `NOTIFY` when a table is changed, so the `LISTEN`ing app hears about the change.  There are examples in the documentation and in Stack Overflow.